# Allow user only to change first digit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/foucpgkL/

```
<input type="text" value=""/>
```

I need to have my textbox containing same value as given i.e 000 not 0

Also I have requirement to allow user to edit only first digit.i.e user should only input like 100,200,500 and not like 123,110 etc.

How can I achieve this using jquery.

I am using Angular Js so angular directive could be best option.

Comment: Make the first digit an option in a `select`, and leave the last part in a readonly `input` or standard HTML element.

Comment: How about number input field `<input value="" step="100" type="number">` ?

Comment: Please find the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/foucpgkL/1/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Cant i use textbox with such a validation to restrict user from editing last two zero.

Comment: <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1"/>  It is allow users to enter only one digit at a time.

Comment: @NitinVarpe you could but it will confuse users as they won't have often seen a control like that, and it can be very easily broken.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elem="000";
$('input').val(elem);
$(".text").keyup(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,1)+"00");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/foucpgkL/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foucpgkL/5/)

```
var elem='000';
$('input').val(elem);
$("input").on('change',function(){
   $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0,1)+'00');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="" step="100" />
```

EDIT:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phxmrah9/1)

My answer was not sufficent so I made a short fiddle.

HTML:

`<input type="number" step="100" value="000" min="0" max="900" onchange="checkZero(this)">`

JS:

`function checkZero(input) {
    if (!parseInt(input.value)){  // if value is not in format "000", is "0" or 0
        input.value = "000";
    }
}`

Use `ng-model` and `ng-change`. I suggest wrapping it in a directive. Feel free to ask for a snippet if you need.

Comment: type needs to be number in order for this to work, and you will have problems with older IEs, because step is not supported there.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes. But now that I read question once again, I think this is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Jquery Mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) for this

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

jQuery(function($){
  $("#myInput").mask("900",{placeholder:"000"});
}
```